# Base58 and utf-8 Encoding Issues in Python 3.6.5

Tags: python, utf-8, base58

I'm using Python 3.6.5.

Hello, I'm having issues with encoding. I believe the issue has something to do with trying to use both base58 and utf-8. This portion of the program worked in Python 2.7.14 and I'm trying to convert it to Python 3.6.5.

```
def save_asset(asset):
nameString = '{0}_!_{1}'.format(asset['Name'].encode('utf-8').strip(), asset['AssetTypeID'])
filename = base58.b58encode(nameString)+'.png'
```

---

Cmd output:

```
File "Transfer.py", line 315, in start_download
    saveAttempt = save_asset(a)
File "Transfer.py", line 221, in save_asset
    filename = base58.b58encode(nameString)+'.png'
TypeError: can't concat str to bytes
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `b58encode` (from whatever library you're using) works in the same peculiar way as `b64encode` from the standard library and returns a byte array, not a text string.

If you want your `filename` to be a byte array, use `b".png"` instead. If you want it to be a text string, decode the bytes returned by `b58encode` by using `.decode("ascii")` (many other encodings should also work, but that one is efficient).

Answer (score 0):

`base58.b58encode(nameString)` is of bytes type. You can not concatenate string `'.png'` with bytes type.

You may use like below

```
filename = base58.b58encode(nameString)+base58.b58encode('.png')
print(filename)
>>b'blah-blah-byte-string'
```